# hibernate not recognising my entities

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to learn hibernate and i'm having a problem with hibernate annotations, the thing is that hibernate doesn't seam to recognise my entity User

```
package com.mycompanyname.myapp;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;


@Entity
@Table(name="FINANCES_USER")
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="USER_ID")
private Long userId;

@Column(name="FIRST_NAME")
private String firstName;

@Column(name="LAST_NAME")
private String lastName;

@Column(name="BIRTH_DATE")
private Date birthDate;

@Column(name="EMAIL_ADDRESS")
private String emailAddress;

@Column(name="LAST_UPDATED_DATE")
private Date lastUpdatedDate;

@Column(name="LAST_UPDATED_BY")
private String lastUpdatedBy;

@Column(name="CREATED_DATE")
private Date createdDate;

@Column(name="CREATED_BY")
private String createdBy;

public Long getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId(Long userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public Date getBirthDate() {
    return birthDate;
}

public void setBirthDate(Date birthDate) {
    this.birthDate = birthDate;
}

public String getEmailAddress() {
    return emailAddress;
}

public void setEmailAddress(String emailAddress) {
    this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
}

public Date getLastUpdatedDate() {
    return lastUpdatedDate;
}

public void setLastUpdatedDate(Date lastUpdatedDate) {
    this.lastUpdatedDate = lastUpdatedDate;
}

public String getLastUpdatedBy() {
    return lastUpdatedBy;
}

public void setLastUpdatedBy(String lastUpdatedBy) {
    this.lastUpdatedBy = lastUpdatedBy;
}

public Date getCreatedDate() {
    return createdDate;
}

public void setCreatedDate(Date createdDate) {
    this.createdDate = createdDate;
}

public String getCreatedBy() {
    return createdBy;
}

public void setCreatedBy(String createdBy) {
    this.createdBy = createdBy;
}

}
```

this is my main

```
package com.mycompanyname.myapp;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.metamodel.MetadataSources;
import com.mycompanyname.myapp.User;
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // A SessionFactory is set up once for an application!
        SessionFactory sessionFactory =null;
        final StandardServiceRegistry registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .configure() // configures settings from hibernate.cfg.xml
                .build();
        try {
             sessionFactory = new MetadataSources( registry ).buildMetadata().buildSessionFactory();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // The registry would be destroyed by the SessionFactory, but we had trouble building the SessionFactory
            // so destroy it manually.
            StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy( registry );
        }

    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    User user1 = new User();
    user1.setUserId((long)234);
    session.save(user1);
    //session.close();
    }

}
```

this is my hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory name="HibernateUtil">
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">database</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/financialanalysis</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">postgres</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>

        <mapping class="com.mycompanyname.myapp.User"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

this exception keeps popping out

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.mycompanyname.myapp.User
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1096)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionImpl.java:1443)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:209)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:715)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:707)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:702)
    at com.mycompanyname.myapp.Application.main(Application.java:32)
```

so what am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is an issue with the way you configure `SessionFactory`. I created a sample application based on the source code you have provided. I suspect there is something wrong with this line.

`sessionFactory = new MetadataSources( registry ).buildMetadata().buildSessionFactory();`

So I would take a different approach to configure session factory like this.

```
 SessionFactory sessionFactory =null;

    try {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure();
        final ServiceRegistry registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(registry);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        sessionFactory.close();
    }

    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    User user1 = new User();
    user1.setUserId((long)234);
    session.save(user1);
    session.close();
```

Looking at the source code `configuration.configure()` method also finds the default `hibernate.cfg.xml` file on the classpath as `new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure()` does. With these configurations in place now you should be able to persist/load/update entities without any issue.

I tested this configuration with a quick and dirty sample application using Hibernate 4.0.

Answer (score 1):

Just use this to build a session factory

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
```

It works for Hibernate 4 and Hibernate 5. This code has a deprecation in Hibernate 4, but this deprecation is removed in Hibernate 5.

Comment: i'm working with hibernate 5.1 thank you this is much simpler :)

Answer (score 1):

configure your `User class` like-

```
Configuration cfg=new Configuration(); 
cfg.addAnnotatedClass(com.mycompanyname.myapp.User.class);
cfg.configure();
```

hope it help.

Comment: yes i tried that but it seems like there is incompatibility issue. i'm using hibernate 5.1 and for the configuration object it tells me that there is no method with the name addAnnotatedClass i thing they moved the method to the MetadataSources Object

Comment: @ AchrafElafrit please update your jars.  
hibernate - 3.2.6.ga, hibernate-annotations - 3.2.1.ga, hibernate-commons-annotations - 3.0.0.ga, hibernate-entitymanager - 3.2.1.ga and let me know.